# Unity collision bounces off, but no OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

I have a problem with Unity collision system.

I'm trying to add some 3d objects(rocks) to my scene **with mesh collider**(convex mesh collider ticked), but **no rigidbody**. I have a bullet prefab **with rigidbody and sphere collider**. I attached a script to the bullet prefab, that **OnCollisionEnter** it should destroy the bullet prefab and play an explosion particle.

Now the problem is that when I shoot the bullet towards the 3d object (rock) it **bounces off instead of exploding**( aka no OnCollisionEnter called). With other colliders like box, capsule or terrain collider it works just fine.

I tried to **add a rigidbody** to it, after which it starts working, **OnCollisionEnter is called** and the bullet explodes, **but the problem with this is that I can move the 3d object with physics which I shouldn't be able to**. To solve this i **tried to constraint in the inspector the position and rotation**, which I thought solved my problem, because the **bullet explodes on contact** and the **3d object won't move**, but now my other problem is that **I can walk through the object**...

**Any idea how to solve my problem? So that I would have a 3d object with meshcollider calling OnCollisionEnter on contact with a sphere collider, but not letting me pass trough it?**

**Edit1**: Forgot to mention that I already **tried IsKinematic** same rule applies, bullet bounces off, but no OnCollisionEnter called.

**Edit2, somewhat solution:** I ended up **duplicating** the object, removing mesh renderer from second one scaling it a little bit and removing Gravity and IsKinematic, this way that layer triggers OnCollisionEnter and my bullet explodes, the original is let at IsKinematic witch don't let me go trough the object and because the other layer is a little bit bigger the bullet can't bounce off. Even though this seems to work, for me it seems a little bit over kill and probably gives me an overhead, is there any better solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what's causing the problem. I set the sphere collider radius way too small (0.025 instead of 0.5, dunno how xD my fault) and for some strange reason with dynamic continuous physics it was detecting collision but no event was raised. Only when collided with terrain or basic shapes, but not with mesh collider.

It's an interesting behavior, but at least now I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the physics of the object ( and I'm not sure if you've done this already ) try clicking on the object, go to the Rigidbody component, and disable the gravity check box ( assuming you don't want gravity applied ) and enable the "is Kinematic" check-box. Kinematic tells unity to not apply physics to your object.

edit: also make sure to undo the fixed positioning that you currently have, if is Kinematic is working for you, that is.

Comment: Tried it already, it has same behavior. Bullet bounces off, but no OnCollisionEnter called.

Comment: Could you post the script that you're using? One solution would be to use OnTriggerEnter but I can best help you if I can see your code. Also for your edit2, its really clever but I would stay away from having two objects rendered, it would increase your overhead dramatically is you had, say, 100 objects -- making it 200 roughly ( not to mention the extra drawcalls etc )

Comment: Well no extra drawcalls because as I said i removed mesh renderer from second one. I tried even with OnTriggerEnter, and didn't seemed to work neither.
But it's not about the code, I tried to just call Debug.Log("test"); OnCollisionEnter and still nothing. The Actual code now 

`void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
 {
Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(explosionSound,transform.position);
Destroy(gameObject);
}`

Comment: Hmmm strange, its hard to tell whats going on from this end. One this is that you don't need to pass in Collision col if you don't call that specific object ( OnCollisionEnter( ) works just fine ). Have you tried raycasts? It usually works better for projectiles since sometimes projectiles can move so fast they aren't detected by colliders. I can provide an example if you want.

Comment: But that's the problem it bounces off the object, not going trough... If it would go trough it, then it would be clear that no collision detected, but it bounces off physically correct, that's why I'm confused why isn't the OnCollisionEnter is called... The raycasting would be a temporary solution which would work in this case, but I need to get this working, because I get the same behavior from every type of 3d object imported in as long as they have mesh collider instead of primitives.

Answer (score -1):

Something i overlooked that might help somebody. I was trying to detect 3D collisions when my game was using 2D physics. So for example if your using BoxCollider**2D** make sure you use OnCollisionEnter**2D**(Collision**2D** collision)